# Adding Modal true to dialog disables the entire popup

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

I am using Jquery dialog , as shown

```
$("#createDialog").dialog("option", "title", 'Create User232' );
$("#createDialog").dialog("option", "modal", true );  
$("#createDialog").dialog("open");
```

After using this line `$("#createDialog").dialog( "option", "modal", true );` all the HTML Components  opened in that pop up (TextBox , combo box) 
are in disabled  state

Answer (score 1):

Its probably better to make so:

```
$( "#createDialog" ).dialog({ title: "Create User232", 
                              modal: true});
```

This will automatically initialize and opens dialog;
If you need to open it later, make so:

```
$( "#createDialog" ).dialog({ title: "Create User232", 
                              modal: true, 
                              autoOpen: false});
```

and later just call "open" method.